# How to run Gitlab CI only for specific branches and tags?

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to setup my `project_dev` CI only for 3 branches and specific kind of tags like: **dev_1.0, dev_1.1, dev_1.2**.

How can I achieve that?

This is what I have now:

```
project_dev:
  stage: dev
  script:
    - export
    - bundle exec pod repo update
    - bundle exec pod install
    - bundle exec fastlane crashlytics_project_dev
  after_script:
    - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives || true
  when: manual
  only:
    - develop
    - release
    - master
    - //here I need to add condition to fire that stage additionally only for specific tags. How can I setup regexp here?
  tags:
    - iOS
```

When I type it like:

```
  only:
    - branches
    - /^dev_[0-9.]*$/
```

It also runs the CI for tags like: **dev1.2** but it should not. Why? Is there a regexp for tags at all?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Sounds like a regular expression question. I just created a [project](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/ci-playground/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L12) on gitlab.com for [the regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/SMeXVe/1).

File: [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/ci-playground/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L4)

```
project_dev:
  # Irrelevant keys is skipped
  script:
    - echo "Hello World"
  only:
    - develop
    - release
    - master
    - /^dev_[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)+$/ # regular expression
```

I was pushed [all of tags](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/ci-playground/tags) you mentioned to test this regular expression.

[image: Tags]

As you can see , It will match tags like `dev_1.0`, `dev_1.1`, but the job `project_dev` will not be triggered by tag `dev1.2`, You can check the result on [pipeline](https://gitlab.com/Gasol/ci-playground/pipelines) pages

[image: Pipelines]

Comment: doesn't this also run any time a commit is made to develop, release, or master, regardless if the regex matches?  I believe 'only' is an OR (that's how it can run on any of those branches).

Comment: @Gasol I have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604509/how-to-run-gitlab-pipeline-whenever-someone-creates-a-branch-with-particular-nam). I wanted to see if you can help me out if possible? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 41):

Instead of using *only/except* you can use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) which are more powerful.

Rules support [regex pattern matching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern) in [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) notation.

Your rule for excepting only specific kind of branches/tags like *dev_1.0*, *dev_1.1*, *dev_1.2* should look like:

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^dev_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ || $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^dev_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'
```

Predefined environment variables like **CI_COMMIT_BRANCH** and **CI_COMMIT_TAG** are described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Comment: I ran into this problem too - The docs for CI_COMMIT_BRANCH say "...Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines." - so I don't believe this actually will ever work since if there's a tag name, CI_COMMIT_BRANCH will not be set.

Comment: The variable "CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME" could be used in merge request pipelines.

Comment: Now the link to the documentation about regex is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern

Comment: The link to documentation of regex pattern matching has been updated.

Answer (score 14):

Gitlab.com ?
You could try a combination of `except` and `only`. 
Something like

```
only: 
- tags 
- branches 
except:
- /^(?!(branch1|branch2|branch3|dev_[0-9.]*$)$).*$/
```

The idea being, allowing only branches and tags to trigger a job, with the exception of everything different from branch[1-3] and dev_ branches/tags

Answer (score 3):

And here is the official documentation for this:

[GitLab CI/CD pipeline configuration reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/)

There you find the [section for only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) with the supported regex syntax, although it states that:

> only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.