# How to run build stage in gitlab pipeline on branch creation?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab pipeline which has two stages as shown below:

Below is my current `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  stages:
    - build
    - push

  build:
    image: docker.repo.test.data/stuff/something:latest
    variables:
      LEGACY_VERSION: 10000
    before_script:
      - export CI_PIPE_ID=`expr $CI_PIPE_ID + $OLDER_VERSION`
    script:
      - echo "Building Project"
      - ls -lrth
      - ./build-project

  push:
    stage: push
    image: docker.repo.test.data/stuff/something:latest
    only:
        - master
    script:
      - some stuff here
```

In my `build` stage I try to build my project and in `push` stage I try to push it. My `push` stage only happens if any PR gets merged to master branch or any commit gets added to master branch as I am using `only` there.

**Problem Statement**

Now I want to run my `build` stage for below things as well:

- If someone creates a branch from master which starts with `release-xxx` name then I want to run only `build` stage.
- If  someone creates a branch from a particular commit which starts with `release-xxx` name then I want to run only `build` stage.
- And for all other cases it should run build stage just like it is doing currently in my original `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Is this possible to do by any chance? Right now whenever I create a branch from `master` it doesn't run `build` stage.

Comment: You can use basic regexp in `except/only` stansza. If this does not meet your needs, you can use the more flexible `rulles: if` feature. Al this is documented in the [.gitlab-ci.yml reference documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html)

Comment: That part I think I know on how to check for specific branch name - I can use regex as well but my question is how can I run `build` stage as soon as I create a `release-xxx` branch from `master`? I tried it but it doesn't trigger build job at all. `build` stage only runs on commit or PR gets merged but I want it to also run whenever I create a `release-xxx` branch from master. @Zeitounator

Comment: Is this even possible to do btw?

Comment: I'm afraid this is actually not possible as the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable documents only the following possible trigger sources for the ci pipeline: `push, web, schedule, api, external, chat, webide, merge_request_event, external_pull_request_event, parent_pipeline, trigger, or pipeline` => https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: I see. thanks for the link.

Comment: @AndyP I don't get your point. In your case, It always run `build` job when branch is  created. No matter what branch name it is. Did you mean you don't want to trigger `build` job when branch name is `release-xxx`?

Comment: No I mean to say `build` job doesn't run whenever I create a `release-xxx` branch from master and I wanted to do that but looks like it isn't possible as @Zeitounator mentioned

Answer (score 0):

probably you can create if rules like this

```
if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == /branch name/ && $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

According to the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

> The previous latest commit present on a branch or tag. Is always
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for merge request pipelines,
> the first commit in pipelines for branches or tags, or when manually
> running a pipeline.