# Create gitlab pipeline freezing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created gitlab-ci.yml file with code:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - deploy

deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  except: 
      - master
  script:
     - pbifiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 -- '***.pbix')
       for pbifile in pbifiles; do
       echo "Publishin $pbifile to BI-Test...."
       python UploadPBITest.py --files $pbifile
```

But when i push Commit changes, i see on the top message:  Checking pipeline status

In pipeline,jobs tabs i don't see nothing

Comment: Are you using a private on-premise GitLab?

Comment: Yes, it's on-prem

Comment: What version of GitLab did you deploy?

Comment: GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.8.2-ee

Answer (score 0):

Check first if one of the [troubleshooting causes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/troubleshooting.html#checking-pipeline-status-message) would apply in your case:

> This message is shown when the merge request has no pipeline associated with the latest commit yet.
> This might be because:
>
> - GitLab hasn’t finished creating the pipeline yet.
> - You are using an external CI service and GitLab hasn’t heard back from the service yet.
> - You are not using CI/CD pipelines in your project.
> - You are using CI/CD pipelines in your project, but your configuration prevented a pipeline from running on the source branch for your merge request.
> - The latest pipeline was deleted (this is a [known issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/214323)).
> - The source branch of the merge request is on a private fork.

---

The OP adds:

> if I delete except, it's work.
> But I don't understand how can create pipeline for branches? I have a lot of branches with template name `BI-`

As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65260122/6309), you can use `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` or `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` to test your branch name and allow the job only if said name matches what you want:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^BI-.*?$/
```

Comment: it's our first pipeline and he didn't create. we use on-prem gitlab

Comment: @Vlad Is there any issue between GitLab and your Git repository server? A network issue perhaps? Or a permission issue?

Comment: it's one network. how i can view permissions??? i can commit to master

Comment: @Vlad commit is purely a local operation. Can you create a simple job, without network access. Are you using [an external Git repository server](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/)?

Comment: 1) yes
2) we don't use external Git

Comment: if i delete except, it's work. But i don't understand how can create pipeline for branches? I have a lot of branches with template name BI-* (example Bi-1054, BI-1054_2) and when push some changes to this branches i should deploy changes files to service (it do with python script)

Comment: @Vlad I have edited the answer to suggest a possible rule to filter on branch name.

Comment: I tried this

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - deploy

deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^BI-.*?$/'
  script:
     - echo "Deploy pbix file...."


but it doesn't work(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242949/discussion-between-vonc-and-vlad).

Answer (score 0):

If you push code to `master` branch, `Checking pipeline status`  is supposed to appear.

The problem is you should have at least one job run. If you push code to `master` branch, no job is run, and `Checking pipeline status`  will appear.

Solution: to create a useless job.

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - init
  - deploy

useless-job:     
  stage: init  
  script:
     - echo "hello"

...
```